# Every email that I receive gets sent to root@example.com (Postfix on CentOS)

Tags: centos, email, postfix, dovecot

It seems that all emails I receive never make it to my actual inbox. They go to the root email. (in my case this is root@example.com)

Here is my `/var/log/maillog`:

```
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem: disabling TLS support
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: warning: TLS library problem: 12945:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem','r'):
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: warning: TLS library problem: 12945:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: warning: TLS library problem: 12945:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:722:
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: connect from mail-qg0-f49.google.com[209.85.192.49]
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: lost connection after STARTTLS from mail-qg0-f49.google.com[209.85.192.49]
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/cleanup[12950]: 37B923FD30: message-id=<20151111004343.37B923FD30@mail.example.com>
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/qmgr[12940]: 37B923FD30: from=<double-bounce@mail.example.com>, size=901, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[12945]: disconnect from mail-qg0-f49.google.com[209.85.192.49]
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[12951]: warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_alias_domains
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/local[12952]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[12951]: warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_alias_domains
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/local[12952]: 37B923FD30: to=<root@example.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/qmgr[12940]: 37B923FD30: removed
```

Here is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/mydomains

queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_interfaces = all
# inet_interfaces = localhost
# mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES


myhostname = mail.example.com
# mydestination = $myhostname
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydestination = mail.example.com, example.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
# mydestination = localhost $mydomain, localhost
# mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.example.com
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
home_mailbox = mail/
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, smtpd_client_restrictions, reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom


smtpd_milters           = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters   = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action   = accept
milter_protocol         = 2
```

I have nothing setup in my `/etc/postfix/virtual` file. I'm not sure if that is important at this point.

Here is `/etc/aliases`:

```
# Basic system aliases -- these MUST be present.
mailer-daemon:  postmaster
postmaster:     root

# General redirections for pseudo accounts.
bin:            root
daemon:         root
adm:            root
lp:             root
sync:           root
shutdown:   root
halt:           root
mail:           root
news:           root
uucp:           root
operator:   root
games:          root
gopher:         root
ftp:            root
nobody:         root
radiusd:        root
nut:            root
dbus:           root
vcsa:           root
canna:          root
wnn:            root
rpm:            root
nscd:           root
pcap:           root
apache:         root
webalizer:  root
dovecot:        root
fax:            root
quagga:         root
radvd:          root
pvm:            root
amandabackup:           root
privoxy:        root
ident:          root
named:          root
xfs:            root
gdm:            root
mailnull:   root
postgres:   root
sshd:           root
smmsp:          root
postfix:        root
netdump:        root
ldap:           root
squid:          root
ntp:            root
mysql:          root
desktop:        root
rpcuser:        root
rpc:            root
nfsnobody:  root

ingres:         root
system:         root
toor:           root
manager:        root
dumper:         root
abuse:          root

newsadm:        news
newsadmin:  news
usenet:         news
ftpadm:         ftp
ftpadmin:   ftp
ftp-adm:        ftp
ftp-admin:  ftp
www:            webmaster
webmaster:  root
noc:            root
security:   root
hostmaster:     root
info:           postmaster
marketing:  postmaster
sales:          postmaster
support:        postmaster


# trap decode to catch security attacks
decode:         root

# Person who should get root's mail
#root:          marc
```

Comment: Aliases issue? Look in `/etc/aliases`, and add the contents if any to your question.

Comment: Just added it to the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See the warning in the error log:

```
Nov 10 19:43:43 mail postfix/trivial-rewrite[12951]: warning: do not list
domain dougbeney.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_alias_domains
```

That means exactly what it says.  Don't do that.  A domain can be either in `mydestination` or it can be a virtual domain in `virtual_alias_domains`. It can't be both.

2. what's in your milter?  is it quarantining the incoming message by delivering it to root?